# How can I get the Authorization Code from the OAuth 2.0 request with Authorization Code Grant?

Tags: web-services, oauth-2.0

I am creating an OAuth 2.0 client which can fetch access tokens for all the requests just like the postman or SOAP UI.

When we Redirect the user to the Auth URL, the server sends the Authorization Code in return back to the client and immediately it redirects to the redirect URI.

I want to fetch the Authorization Code.

Example :

Let's consider the example of Google :

For Google suppose we have :

Auth URI: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth

Redirect URI: https://www.example.com/oauth2/callback

the first step will be to redirect to Auth URI with client id and redirect URI as parameters :

For this I have used following in MVC :

```
    public ActionResult LoginUsingGoogle()
    {
        return Redirect($"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id={ClientId}&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20profile&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}&state=abcdef");
    }
```

Once it redirects successfully it send authorization code in return which can further be used to fetch access token.

I want to fetch this authorization code so that I can further hit a POST request with authorization code as a parameter to fetch access token.

How can I fetch this intermediate authorization code?

How tools like Postman and SOAP UI make it possible to read authorization code?

Also :

1. The redirect URI is not on my server, it can be anywhere.
2. I am trying to do it from MVC that is why I have used [Response.Redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: On redirection when the pages loads you can check if there is "code" query string parameter available if yes extract that and then use this code to exchange access token. you need to redirect to server as the client redirecturi should be a exact match

Comment: @Shantanu  how can i check for redirects in a browser. do i need to hook on the redirects?

Comment: Is there a way in JavaScript to check for redirects?

Comment: Redirect are nothing but a get call to you server so essentially whenever a call is made to redirect uri it has a code in it lets say localhost:1000/login.html?code={code} so on pageinit you need to check if there is any code if yes then get that code and exchange it for access token else show the login page.